# Python function for generalized eigenvalues of two non-square matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am looking for a Python function/library that finds the generalized eigenvalues of two non-square matrices, as described in [this](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/epdf/10.1137/050628258) paper. The only implementation I could find (in scipy) for generalized eigenvalues assumes the matrices A and B in the matrix pencil are both square. Is there an existing implementation for this (hopefully leveraging numpy)?